# Setter not working for boolean but work fine in string C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, getter-setter

[Error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5yV3.png)

I don't know why setter is not working for bool variable but working fine with string variable. Is bool requires special setter for it?

Comment: Try learning what [`const`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const) means...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you have declared it as const. If a variable is const, it's value can't be changed. What ever value is assigned at declaration, is what it will always hold.